# Unable to insert into teradata using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, teradata

I am trying to insert data into Teradata using tasklet and I'm specifying the database in the jdbc url in application.yml file. I am receiving the below error

java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 3802] [SQLState 42S02] Database 'information_schema' does not exist.

information_schema is not the database mentioned in the url. Need help in resolving this error.

P.S: this is my first time using spring batch, I am an IIB Developer.

Comment: please share yaml config

Comment: driver-class-name: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
    username: XXXXXX
    password: XXXXXX
    jdbc-url: jdbc:teradata://serverurl/DATABASE=HTODS,DBS_PORT=1025,TMODE=ANSI,LOB_SUPPORT=OFF
    validationQuery: SELECT 1

Comment: Springbatch try to create metadata tables while starting up. Can you check the permission of this user have create table access

Comment: Thanks, but I found the issue. The configuration for primary database was missing org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect

Comment: Thank you for the kind update. Seems you were using two data sources but the error should be different in such case.

Comment: Yes, the configuration was wrong, it was pointing to a different database which had information_schema